# List Group Members (contacts)?

Tags: android, contacts

I can get a list of groups with the code below and I've bound them to a ListView.  It's clickable and I get the NAME and _ID of the group.  Similarly I can get a list of contacts with similar code.  What I haven't been able to figure out is how to select a group and return only the contacts in that group.

I'm really trying to target Android 1.5.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor groupCur = cr.query(Groups.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (groupCur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (groupCur.moveToNext()) {

        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: can you post example to select list of people by Group._ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the help here: [Click Listener on ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170794/click-listener-on-listview)

I was able to get a Group._ID from the click and pass that to GroupMembership to get a list of people and finally query People with an IN where clause to get the members.